# functions which() and match() do not work on descending sequences

Tags: r, arrays, sequence

I have come across an odd thing I can't explain:

I am trying to find indices of elements from one vector in another vector, and I can do this with `which()` or `match()`:

```
test = seq(.1, 10, .1)
match(c(0.1, 0.2, 4, 7), test)
[1]  1  2 40 70
which(test %in% c(0.1, 0.2, 4, 7))
[1]  1  2 40 70
```

This makes sense, but if I reverse the sequence:

```
test = seq(10, .1, -.1)
match(c(0.1, 0.2, 4, 7), test)
[1] 100  NA  61  31
which(test %in% c(0.1, 0.2, 4, 7))
[1]  31  61 100
```

it cannot find `0.2`. My initial guess was that the format is not right, but it also cannot find `0.200` or `test[99]`

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: It is a float object.  So precision is important i.e. ` match(c(0.1, 0.2, 4, 7), round(test, 1))`

Comment: [`seq(.1, 10, .1) == rev(seq(10, .1, -.1))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: This is the usual issue:  your descending sequence doesn't contain 0.2.  See R FAQ 7.31.